# Material-UI tab not displaying component report on page render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, tabs, material-ui

I have the following material-ui tab setup with react-router but when this page renders, it displays the tabs names: `Tab A` and `Tab B` and that's it, until the user actually clicks on `Tab A` and then the `TabAReport` component is rendered.

I actually want the `TabAReport` component to automatically display on page render but for some reason, it doesn't.

I believe I have set the required values for the first tab to display automatically.

Any assistance would be great

```
           const routes = ["/tab-a-report", "/tab-b-report"];

          <Tabs
            value={0}
            onChange={handleChange}
            textColor="default"
            variant="standard"                                                   
          >
            <Tab 
              value={0}
              label="Tab A" 
              component={Link}
              to={`${routes[0]}/${id}`}
            />
            <Tab 
              value={1}
              label="Tab B" 
              component={Link}
              to={`${routes[1]}/${id}`}
            />
          </Tabs>

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/tab-a-report/:id" component={TabAReport} />
          <Route exact path="/tab-b-report/:id" component={TabBReport} />
        </Switch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by specifying a route without a path as the last child of the Switch element. This route will be rendered if none of the other routes' path's matches the actual path. See [React Router: Switch](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch) for more details.

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/tab-a-report/:id" component={TabAReport} />
    <Route exact path="/tab-b-report/:id" component={TabBReport} />
    <Route><TabAReport id={id} /></Route> //pass the default id as property
</Switch>
```

To access the :id parameter within the child component, use the [useParam hook](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks) or read it from the properties in the default case.

`const { id } = useParams() || {id: props.id}`

Comment: But as part of the route, I pass in the `:id` as now, it displays but returns no data since it requires the `id`. Any ideas pls?

Comment: If you don't want to specify an id but want to render a default component, you'd have to define a default Id within the component.

Comment: Understand that I can use the useParam hook but as part of the last child of switch element, the `:id` is not being passed and I need the `id`.  Can you pls explain how to use this useParam hook when no route is provided?

Comment: If you want to render a component, which requires an `id`, by default (without specifying the route path with `id`) then you will have to define how your component should behave when no `id` is specified. For instance, you could work with a default `id`. If you have the `id` in the parent component that contains the Switch you could pass it as props.

Comment: FYI, I am already using the useParams hook within my component as I am always expecting an id, i.e. `const { id } = useParams();` Sorry, but I don't follow with regards to when no `id` is specified as I need to use the job `id` the user clicked on, to produce required report.

Comment: Sorry I got a little confused. You have the `id` in the parent component, correct? Then you can just pass it as property. I updated the code sample.

Comment: No probs. So with passing it as a prop can I still use the existing `const { id } = useParams()` to pick up this prop value?

Comment: All good now but thanks for offering the chat.

Comment: `const { id } = useParams() || {id: props.id}`